# Finding average for an array of elements one at a time

Tags: numbers, average

I have an array of numbers which are prices of a stock as given below:

```
double[] xyz=new double{ 10.1, 20.34, 35.46, 78.34, 98.67, 43.73 ........}
```

Now, I want to find the average of stock based on time:

> 1st min  =  Average(10.1)  = 10.1
>
> 2nd min  =  Average(10.1 + 20.34) =  15.22
>
> 3rd min  =  Average(10.1 + 20.34 + 35.46) = 21.96

One way of doing this is to loop minutes times(1,2,3,4...) and find the average. But, as my list is very huge, this can become a performance issue.

Is there any other way of finding average each time?

Thanks a lot.

Mahesh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, maintain a running sum:

```
sum = 0;
num = 0;

foreach (element i)
{
    sum += i;
    num ++;
    average = sum / num;
}
```

Choose a big enough type for `sum` such that it won't ever overflow.

Comment: You could also create an array of averages and populate that as you iterate over each element.

Comment: I have to show only the latest average in the UI. After looking at various options below, I used Oli's solution as it is best in terms of memory and performance.

Comment: @Mahesh if you have to show only last average then you just have to calculate sum and then divide **once**.

Comment: @Andrey I have to show only one average at a time. So, no need to hold all the averages in the memory.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate them in `O(n)` (in single pass) by using following recursive formula:

`An` means n-th minute average, `Vn` - n-th minute price.

```
An = (An-1 * (n - 1) + Vn) / n
```

So you loop and keep previous `An`.

**PS**: If i understood you correctly you want to find average of prices for every minute, not single average.

Comment: Mathematically, this works fine.  In practice, this will have cumulative errors, which will cause successive results to drift.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth true. but it doesn't require big variable for running sum.

Answer (score 0):

You need some form of persistence.

Perhaps an object ?  AverageObj that contains a counter and a sum field.

Answer (score 0):

```
double[] xyz=new double{ 10.1, 20.34, 35.46, 78.34, 98.67, 43.73 ........ }

double[] averages = new double[xyz.Length];

averages[0] = xyz[0];
for(int i = 1; i < xyz.Length; i++)
{
  averages[i] = (((averages[i-1] * i) + xyz[i])/i+1);
}
```